# Marketing Cloud UTM issue: Parameter Manager + Redirect issue + AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, redirect, parameters

Im facing a redirect issue in my MC email links.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Creating a dynamic link with AMPscript

Example:
SET @magentourl = CONCAT('https://www.example.*/cart-link/cart/restore?token=',@magentotoken)

Button click
href="%%=RedirectTo(@magentourl)=%%"

2. Using the parameter mananager

sfmc_sub2=%%*subscriberkey%%​&utm_source=blabla&utm_medium=%%emailname*%%​&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%​&utm_term=term​&utm_id=%%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%

3. I put the qs url in https://wheregoes.com/retracer.php
4. output where goes.com:

302 Redirect
What I want to see in browser and only see in wheregoes.com
https://www.example.*/cart-link/cart/restore?token=blabla&sfmc_sub2=blabla&utm_source=MCnieuwsbrief&utm_medium=blabla&utm_campaign=blabla&utm_term=term&utm_id=blabla

302 Redirect

What I see in Browser:
https://www.example.*/checkout/cart/?sfmc_sub2=blabla&utm_id=1

What should I do, to be able to use a dynamic build up link in combination with the parameter manager.

Note: Parameter manager works with a static link. I need to see the UTM paramater in GA in combination with a dynamic build up link in AMPscript.

Any suggestions?

Robin

Comment: In my experience, 98% of the time the reason the parameters are stripped is because the resolving page that's redirecting visitors is not set up to carry the parameters to the final page. The remaining 2% is because of an extra "?" or a bad character in the URL. Of note, URLs in the email that are wrapped for tracking, should look more like "https://click.example.com?qs=encryptedParameters".

Comment: Are you getting two "?"s in your query string?

Comment: @EduardoArias  https://click.example.*/?qs=blabla
302 Redirect
https://www.example.*/cart-link/cart/restore?token=blabla&sfmc_sub2=blabla&utm_source=blabla&utm_medium=blabla&utm_campaign=blabla&utm_term=term&utm_id=9

302 Redirect
https://www.example.*/checkout/cart/?sfmc_sub2=blabla&utm_id=9
 I Dont see double "?" in the url. But I see a double redirect. This URL I can see in the browser: 302 Redirect
https://www.example.*/checkout/cart/?sfmc_sub2=blabla&utm_id=9. How should I build a dynamic link with the UTM parameters from the parameter manager in AMPscript? The URL. Robin

Comment: @RobSource - your code looks good, the issue is with the landing page. Seeing that the parameters are still in place on the first page - means it's working, but when it gets redirected to the next, it resolves to page that loses the parameters - is something the webmaster of the website has to fix/address. You can point it to the final page (like changing the original URL in your email), however, if that is not an option, there's nothing you can do on the email side to resolve that.

Comment: @macca Thank you for the response. The webmaster is going to resolve the redirect of utm parameters. Thanks for the input all!